# Setting a query timeout in Wikidata api

Tags: wikidata, wikidata-api, blazegraph

I've created a local version of the wikidata api using the instructions [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_query_service/User_Manual#Standalone_service), and I'd like to specify a custom timeout to override the 60 second timeout in the [official api](https://query.wikidata.org/). I haven't found anything in `RWStore.properties`, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: Look into `web.xml` (within .war file, inside `WEB-INF` folder).

Comment: @StanislavKralin please write your comment as an answer, and I'll be happy to accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Blazegraph [documentation](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/NanoSparqlServer#web.xml), this should be the `queryTimeout` parameter in the [`web.xml`](https://github.com/wikimedia/wikidata-query-rdf/blob/ee8d52bff0d0e3b2f67dbee6f91811f5971329bf/war/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml#L58) file.

Answer (score 4):

Using the pre-built full service package (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual#Standalone_service) with `blazegraph-service-0.3.0.war`, without a `web.xml` or other files to modify, there's also following way to adjust the query timeout limit:

Open the `runBlazegraph.sh` file and append following option:

`-Dorg.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.rdf.RdfRepository.timeout=3600`

to the java options.

This would increase the timeout time to 1 hour (3600s).

Comment: Instead of editing the script, you can also pass the option to the script with `runBlazegraph.sh -o '-Dorg.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.rdf.RdfRepository.timeout=3600'`. A little caution is required though if the option is already added; in general it will add the option towards the end so it should override what was already set, but this is not set in stone and might depend on the JVM.